# The emulator process for avd has terminated 2022 new on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I am trying realy hard to make Android studio work but life is not eazy right now. I tried everything related to the "the emulator process for avd has terminated" problem. I have enough space on my disk, I tried so many other stuff that I saw on youtube and in here but nothing is working... I am a big newbie in the android dev world...

plz help me !

I tried : Tutorial about creating a txt file on the .android file (not working),
Trying under 30 api (not working) and I have enough space on my computer

Comment: Have you restarted your computer?

Comment: yes , more then  3 times...